# Prove that $(\mathcal{C}^{(1)}([a,b]),||\cdot||^{(1)})$ is a Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I have to prove this:

> Show that the space $\mathcal{C}^{(1)}([a,b])$ with respect to the norm $||\cdot||^{(1)}$ is a Banach Space

where $||\cdot||^{(1)} = |f(a)|+||f'||_{\infty}$. In the proof I use this theorem (D):

> Let $I$ be a real limited interval, $c\in I$. Let $f_n:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose for each $n$ that $f_n\in\mathcal{C}^{(1)}(I)$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ exists for some $x_0\in I$ and $\{f'_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $I$, then $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $I$ and $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)\right)$$

My proof:

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{C}^{(1)}([a,b])$  be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{C}^{(1)}([a,b])$, then
$$
  \forall\epsilon > 0\;\exists n_0=n_0(\epsilon) : |f_n(a)-f_m(a)|+||f'_n(x)-f'_m(x)||_{\infty}<\epsilon \quad\forall n,m>n_0 
$$
in particular
$$
|f_n(a)-f_m(a)|<\epsilon \text{ and } ||f'_n(x)-f'_m(x)||_{\infty}<\epsilon
$$
so $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ and $\{f'_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{C}^{(0)}([a,b]),||\cdot||_{\infty})$.

Since $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ and $\mathcal{C}^{(0)}([a,b]),||\cdot||_{\infty})$ are complete spaces,
\begin{align*}
  f_n(a)&\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow+\infty}f(a)\in\mathbb{R}\\
  f'_n&\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow+\infty}g\in\mathcal{C}^{(0)}([a,b]).
\end{align*}

By theorem (D) $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f\in\mathcal{C}^{(1)}([a,b])$ and $f'(x)=g(x)\;\forall x\in[a,b]$.

I have to prove that $f$ is the limit with respect to the norm $||\cdot||^{(1)}$, i.e. that
$$
  ||f_n(x)-f(x)||^{(1)}= |f_n(a)-f(a)|+||f'_n(x)-f'(x)||_{\infty}\rightarrow 0 \text{ for } n\rightarrow+\infty
$$

I have already shown that $f_n(a)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow+\infty}f(a)\in\mathbb{R}$. Regarding
$$
  \sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f'_n(x)-f'(x)| = \sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f'_n(x)-g(x)|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow+\infty}0,
$$
therefore $||f_n(x)-f(x)||^{(1)}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow+\infty}0$.

Is this proof correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!